# Why does MailItem.Body return $null after being set?

Tags: powershell, outlook, outlook-addin

I have run the following code on two machines:

```bsh
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$m = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$m.Body = "ASDF"
Write-Host $m.Body
```

On my **personal machine** (Windows 10 64-bit, Outlook (Office16) 64-bit), this outputs "ASDF".

```
$Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  145

$ol.Application.Version

16.0.0.11929
```

On my **work machine** (Windows 10 64-bit, Outlook (Office16) 32-bit), **$m.Body is returned as null** and only empty lines are output. I have tried both 32- and 64-bit versions of PowerShell.

```
$Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  1146

$ol.Application.Version

16.0.0.4705
```

Calling `$m.Display()` on both machines yields the expected result: an email with "ASDF" as the body. The issue is that I cannot read/get the mail body programmatically.

---

**Why does $m.Body appear to be null when I try to read it on my work machine?**

---

**Update**

I have tried the following code but it only outputs blank lines:

```bsh
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$m = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$m.Body = "ASDF"
Write-Host $m.Body
$m.Save()
$m.Body = "ASDF"
Write-Host $m.Body
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook caches values, so it is better to submit your changes by calling `Save`.

Try to use the [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.save) method to make your changes permanent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this didn't work. Any other ideas?